# Is there a word for words that imitate a feeling or mood?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

Something like an onomatopoeia for sensations other than auditive?

Comment: Can you show us some examples or context where the word would be used?

Comment: Ideally, this question should carry the [tag:single-word-requests] tag and an example sentence with some context.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since words **are** sound, the only thing they can actually **imitate** is a sound.

But there **are** word chunks that have semantics, and they include plenty of emotional terms.
The usual technical term for this phenomenon is ***[Sound Symbolism](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20sound%20symbolism)***.

For instance, the set of English simplex words [beginning with /kl-/](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf) is remarkably coherent.